# I keep getting this error message whenever i try to run flutter from git or any CLI

Tags: flutter, flutter-downloader

```
hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 ~
$ cd c:\Dev

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev
$ git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Cloning into 'flutter'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 475395, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (104/104), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
remote: Total 475395 (delta 47), reused 73 (delta 29), pack-reused 475291
Receiving objects: 100% (475395/475395), 264.12 MiB | 109.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (366536/366536), done.
Updating files: 100% (7876/7876), done.

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121 0 Oct 21 22:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121 0 Oct 20 10:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121 0 Oct 21 22:52 flutter/

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev
$ cd flutter

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter (master)
$ cd bin

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter/bin (master)
$ ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121    0 Oct 21 22:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121    0 Oct 21 22:52 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121 2204 Oct 21 22:52 dart*
-rw-r--r-- 1 hp 197121 1488 Oct 21 22:52 dart.bat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121 2436 Oct 21 22:52 flutter*
-rw-r--r-- 1 hp 197121 2544 Oct 21 22:52 flutter.bat
drwxr-xr-x 1 hp 197121    0 Oct 21 22:52 internal/

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter/bin (master)
$ flutter run
/c/Dev/flutter/bin/flutter: line 58: /c/Dev/flutter/bin/flutter.bat: No such file or directory

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter/bin (master)
$ where flutter dart
C:\Dev\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\Dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
C:\Dev\flutter\bin\dart
C:\Dev\flutter\bin\dart.bat

hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter/bin (master)
$   PS where.exe flutter dart
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
      367     241     367      20500  pty0      197609 07:39:08 /usr/bin/PS
      239       1     239      10052  ?         197609 22:08:58 /usr/bin/mintty
      241     239     241      17492  pty0      197609 22:08:58 /usr/bin/bash


hp@nickeybamby MINGW64 /c/Dev/flutter/bin (master)
$ flutter
/c/Dev/flutter/bin/flutter: line 58: /c/Dev/flutter/bin/flutter.bat: No such file or directory
```

i have already updated my path on the system environmental variables to C:\Dev\flutter\bin
i have initially downloaded the .zip flutter sdk and extracted the files to my folder of choice and it didn't work. i had to install flutter from git repo and it still did not run. Please help

Comment: I don't know how well the MinGW/Cygwin path in the main `flutter` script has been tested.  It looks like that script tries to execute `flutter.bat` via `exec`, and I don't know if that's correct.  I would recommend executing `flutter` via Windows' normal command prompt, via a PowerShell terminal, or via WSL.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. here is the response I got, 

PS C:\Users\hp> cd "C:\Dev\flutter\bin"
PS C:\Dev\flutter\bin> flutter --version
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 
'C:\Dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat' with working directory 
'C:\Dev\flutter\bin'. The system cannot find the file specified.At line:1 char:1
+ flutter --version

Comment: Well, for anyone who experiences similar challenges in the future, here's what solved the problem for me.

I simply ran the code scf /scannow on PowerShell. It fixed all corrupted files fixed